# Git merge starting from certain commit of the feature branch

Tags: git, github

If I have the following git branches

```
master: A - B - C - DE
         \
topic:    \- D - E - F - G
```

Is there any way to merge commit F and G to master?

The reason I want to do this is that I've already done a pull request from topic to master before I made `commit F` and `commit G` to merge `D` and `E` to after `C`. I did a squash and merge so now `DE` contains the merge of `D` and `E`. Now I need merge only `F` and `G` to master.

Comment: You can just do another PR / merge from `topic` - assuming you still have the local copy, there's nothing stopping you from doing a second merge of the same branch.

Comment: @ObsidianAge the problem I got from doing another PR is that it doesn't recognize that `D` and `E` are already in master. In the new PR from topic to master, Git shows all the four commits (D, E, F, and G), while I only want `F` and `G` appear in the PR.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
git rebase --onto master E topic
```

You are asking git to rebase topic branch on top of master *discarding* revisions up to E (so, basically asking to carry over F and G only).

Results:

```
master: A - B - C - DE
                     \
topic:                F' - G'
```

Then you could merge into master

```
git checkout master
git merge topic
```

Or have the branch move instead:

```
git branch -f master topic
```

Alternatively, you could cherry-pick into master:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick topic~2..topic # bring over the last 2 revisions from topic into master
```